# Delete [] pBuff throws 'c0000374 (heap corruption)' Exception and program crashes

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, richtextbox

In my mfc application, I have a rich text box in which user can enter strings.
When user Enter anything in the rich text box, i have invoked a function 'FormatText(int start, int end)' that formats the text enterd.
in the function i have written following code

```
TCHAR *pBuffer = NULL;


try 
    {
        pBuffer = new TCHAR[nEnd - nStart + 1]; 
            ...
            ...
            ...
    } 
catch(...)
{
}


delete [] pBuffer;
```

but when i enter any values in the rich text box, i get and Exception of Heap memory corruption and program crashes,
when i debugged code, visual studio shows an exception at line,

```
delete [] pBuffer;
```

is there any other way to delete/free the memory. 
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're corrupting the heap. Are you sure you do not write past the end of `pBuffer`?

Answer (score 4):

You have to find and fix the corruption, not look for another way to delete. The heap corruption occured at some time prior to the delete [] operation. That operation merely detects that it happened previously. Comment out some sections of code, and/or replace them with trivial operations, until the corruption goes away. That should help you isolate which code is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really catching all exceptions and silently dropping them? There could be a failed new here (std::bad_alloc)

Are there any checks on nEnd & nStart, making sure the size of the buffer you 'new' is > 0 ?

So, you might want to check pBuffer for NULL before deleting it.

Comment: It's not necessary to check pBuffer vs NULL because language is smart enough. Attempt to delete NULL pointer will pass OK. The only failure possible here is if the pointer not initialized and contains random noice which delete() will treat as an address.